# Why can't I use page overlays with Microsoft Edge?

Tags: overlay, microsoft-edge

I am attempting to use a `<div>` overlay but I am unable to call the overlay from within a function using Microsoft Edge (Chromium version). The overlay works fine with Firefox.

Here's the link to a fiddle which will illustrate my dilemma: https://jsfiddle.net/utd0z7qk/

First, open the link using Firefox then click on the "Check for Errors" button. You will see an `alert` box appear with the message "Check Point". Note, in the background you will also see that an overlay has been invoked with the message "Loading...".

Next, open the same link using Microsoft Edge and click on the "Check for Errors" button. Again, you will see an `alert` box appear with the message "Check Point.. However, note the overlay has not been invoked and there is no message in the background.

Why not?

I make extensive use of `<div>` overlays for messaging purposes, particularly when I am anticipating a noticeable delay in the response from a remote source (e.g. database, web service, REST API, etc). Is there a suitable work-around for this behavior with Microsoft Edge?

**Edited to include code:**

```js
function errorCheck(elem) {
  var ovly = document.getElementById("overlaySpinner");
  var msg = document.getElementById("msgSpinner");
  msg.innerHtml = "CHECKING FOR ERRORS";
  ovly.style.display = "block";

  alert("Check Point");

  ovly.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.overlay {
    position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the page content */
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
    height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00); /* White background with opacity */
/*  background-color: white;
    opacity: 1.00; */
    z-index: 2;  /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different order for other elements */
    cursor: pointer; /* Add a pointer on hover */
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <h5>Overlay Messaging Demo</h5>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button id="btnErrorCheck" style="width:30%;" onclick="errorCheck()">Check for Errors</button>
    </center>

    <!-- Spinner Overlay -->
    <div id="overlaySpinner" class="overlay" style="text-align:center;">
      <div class="text-center" style="height:65%"></div>
      <div class="text-center" style="height:5%">
        <div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
          <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center" style="height:5%; font-family:Arial; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; margin-top:12px;">
        <span id="msgSpinner"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Greetings, currently your question is off-topic, as all questions requiring debugging MUST include the code in the question itself. (Not a screenshot, not an embed link, must be in the question.) You can check it on https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Code snippets have been added.

Comment: That's good. I strongly recommend that you make those snippets into a stacksnippet (CLTR+M on the editing box, or the icon on the right of the image button). This allows people to test it directly in StackOverflow, and then there's no need for the jsfiddle link.

Comment: Got it.  Done.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: If you debug the code using developer tools then you can notice that everything is working correctly but in a normal condition, it looks like code is working fast and it is showing the overlay message and hide it quickly. If you remove the code to hide the message then you can notice the message after you close the alert(). I agree with the suggestion given by the @Ismael Miguel. I suggest you can provide the feedback to the Chromium site. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I agree with you, in a way. You can notice that the `ovly.style.display = "block";` is not running. Maybe it runs after the `alert(...)`, or the DOM just didn't had time to be updated to display the changes, and `alert` is blocking execution, but then `ovly.style.display = "none";` and hides it. But now, it has enough time to run this, until the button is clicked again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested and the problem also happens in Google Chrome:

[image: Google chrome]

Basically, you need to give it time to do the reflow/redraw.

A simple `setTimeout` is enough to test.

Something like changing this:

```js
function errorCheck(elem) {
  var ovly = document.getElementById("overlaySpinner");
  var msg = document.getElementById("msgSpinner");
  msg.innerHtml = "CHECKING FOR ERRORS";
  ovly.style.display = "block";
  
  alert("Check Point");
  
  ovly.style.display = "none";
}
```

Into this:

```js
function errorCheck(elem) {
  var ovly = document.getElementById("overlaySpinner");
  var msg = document.getElementById("msgSpinner");
  msg.innerHtml = "CHECKING FOR ERRORS";
  ovly.style.display = "block";

  setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Check Point");
    
    ovly.style.display = "none";
  }, 2000);
}
```

And the "Loading ..." should show:
[image: Google Chrome - after setTimeout]

(By the way, remember that Microsoft Edge now runs on Blink, just like Google Chrome)

You can try this on the StackSnippet below:

```js
function errorCheck(elem) {
  var ovly = document.getElementById("overlaySpinner");
  var msg = document.getElementById("msgSpinner");
  msg.innerHtml = "CHECKING FOR ERRORS";
  ovly.style.display = "block";

  setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Check Point");
    
    ovly.style.display = "none";
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
.overlay {
    position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the page content */
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
    height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00); /* White background with opacity */
/*  background-color: white;
    opacity: 1.00; */
    z-index: 2;  /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different order for other elements */
    cursor: pointer; /* Add a pointer on hover */
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <h5>Overlay Messaging Demo</h5>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button id="btnErrorCheck" style="width:30%;" onclick="errorCheck()">Check for Errors</button>
    </center>

    <!-- Spinner Overlay -->
    <div id="overlaySpinner" class="overlay" style="text-align:center;">
      <div class="text-center" style="height:45%"></div>
      <div class="text-center" style="height:5%">
        <div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
          <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center" style="height:5%; font-family:Arial; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; margin-top:12px;">
        <span id="msgSpinner"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  Unfortunately, I will need to avoid use of the setTimeout function.  A built-in delay is simply not an option.  I need to achieve the same sequential/synchronous behavior with Chromium browsers that is provided by Firefox.  The alert that was included in my code is there strictly for demonstration purposes.  In reality, I will be making successive calls to an API and will need to provide updated status to the user for each call; hence, the need for the <div> overlay.  Thanks again.

Comment: @rpowell6 The `setTimeout` is an example of "giving it time". If you are making calls for the API, just put the `ovly.style.display = "none";` inside the response handler(s). If you use jQuery, you can use the `.complete` event for this. If you use some other library, use whatever the library provides. You just have to give it time. But this is something you would do anyways, regardless of IE, Edge, Chrome, Firefox .... Or you would be removing the div before the call has finished.

Comment: As suggested by Deepak-MSFT, I have referred the issue to the Chromium development team.  They have acknowledged the bug and have assigned a case number.  While I appreciate the suggestions received regarding this post, my greater concern is with browser cross-compatibility.  In this case, Firefox holds true to the JavaScript sequential/synchronous execution model while Chromium does not.  Hopefully, the issue will be resolved soon.  In the meantime, I will up-vote the solution from Ismael Miguel as an acceptable work-around.